# i need to change a function in a buddypress theme (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, function, buddypress

I'm using the buddypress theme [buddyboss] (http://buddyboss.com/). the main reason was that this theme is able to manage a picture gallery (which works great).

I now want to call that picture-function within the members-loop. one of the buddyboss-admins told me:

> "you will need the functions from buddy_boss_pics.php. Specifically you need to use function buddyboss_pics_screen_picture_grid_content() starting from line: 285. You will need to edit the file to work with the members-loop since it currently uses displayed_user_id."

this is how the function looks:

```
function buddyboss_pics_screen_picture_grid_content()
{
    global $bp, $wpdb, $bbpics;

    $wpdb->show_errors = BUDDY_BOSS_DEBUG;

    $img_size = is_active_sidebar( 'Profile' ) ? 'buddyboss_pic_med' : 'buddyboss_pic_wide';

    $gallery_class = is_active_sidebar( 'Profile' ) ? 'gallery has-sidebar' : 'gallery';

    $user_id = $bp->displayed_user->id;
    $activity_table = $wpdb->prefix."bp_activity";
    $activity_meta_table = $wpdb->prefix."bp_activity_meta";

    $pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $activity_table a INNER JOIN $activity_meta_table am ON a.id = am.activity_id WHERE a.user_id = $user_id AND meta_key = 'bboss_pics_aid'";

    $bbpics->grid_num_pics = $wpdb->get_var($pages_sql);

    $bbpics->grid_current_page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;

    // Prepare a SQL query to retrieve the activity posts 
    // that have pictures associated with them
    $sql = "SELECT a.*, am.meta_value FROM $activity_table a INNER JOIN $activity_meta_table am ON a.id = am.activity_id WHERE a.user_id = $user_id AND meta_key = 'bboss_pics_aid' ORDER BY a.date_recorded DESC";

    buddy_boss_log("SQL: $sql");

    $pics  = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);

    $bbpics->grid_pagination = new BuddyBoss_Paginated( $pics, $bbpics->grid_pics_per_page, $bbpics->grid_current_page );

    buddy_boss_log("RESULT: $pics");

    // If we have results let's print out a simple grid
    if ( !empty( $pics ) )
    {
        $bbpics->grid_had_pics = true;
        $bbpics->grid_num_pics = count( $pics );
```

Any help would be great because I really need to do it!

Comment: You may get an answer on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Untested- but try this:

In members-loop, look for

```
                <?php
             /***
              * If you want to show specific profile fields here you can,
              * but it'll add an extra query for each member in the loop
              * (only one regadless of the number of fields you show):
              *
              * bp_member_profile_data( 'field=the field name' );
              */
            ?>
```

Add this before the close php tag ?>

```
             buddyboss_pics_members_loop( bp_get_member_user_id() );
```

Copy the buddyboss_pics_screen_picture_grid_content() function to the bottom of members-loop.

Put it between php tags and change the name to 
     buddyboss_pics_members_loop( $user_id )

and comment out or delete 
    $user_id = $bp->displayed_user->id;

Comment: hey.. your description seems to be pretty clear but it doesn't work!?!? the thing is: the picture-grid does not show up but instead all the other users disappear... damn

Comment: i uploaded the two example-files.. maybe you can show me how to do it right... http://ge.tt/3uWNXYG/v/0?c

Answer (score 0):

Here the buddyboss_pics_screen_picture_grid_content() function are mainly use the user_id and get the image from the database.

Simple you have called the function within the while loop in member-loop.php file:
`buddyboss_pics_screen_picture_grid_content(bp_member_user_id())`

Here pass the parameter member_user_id of this function.

Little edit the main `buddyboss_pics_screen_picture_grid_content()` function below:

Below changes:

```
function buddyboss_pics_screen_picture_grid_content($user_id = null)
{

    //Remove this code
    $user_id = $bp->displayed_user->id;

    //Put new Code
    if (empty($user_id)) {
        $user_id = $bp->displayed_user->id;
    } else {
        $user_id = $user_id;
    }

}
```